Godot 4.3 Мобы застревают друг в друге
Я работаю над игрой в стиле Моба на движке Godot 4.3 и у меня возникла проблема, когда мобы движутся что бы атаковать одну и ту же цель они могут мешать друг друга подойти

Нод navigationAgent2d выглядит так


Попробуйте отключить Avoidance Mask (кликните на единичку)
